# Using Dictionary in Numpy Array dosent make that array to have single Data Type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

I am new to python and learning Numpy. What i have read and tested is that np.array has single data type. When I use it on normal code, it works and behaves well. i.e

```
import numpy as np 
np1 = np.array([1,'2' , True])

for i in np1:
   print(type(i))
```

Answer is

```
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

But when my code is

```
np2 = np.array([{1:1 , 2:2 }, 1 , True , '1'])
for i in np2:
    print(type(i))
```

Answer is

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'str'>
```

Which shows that elements are not of numpy class as above answer was `<class 'numpy.str'>`.
When I printed `print(type(np2))` , Answer was `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.
Can you explain why they are not of the same data type.? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the desired datatype for the array is not given, then the type "*will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.*"

In the first case, the minimum type is `str`, because each item can be converted to a string. The new array holds strings.

In the second case, the minimum type is `object` (because `<class 'str'>` and `dict` cannot be converted to strings). The new array holds references to objects. Each object has its own type.

You can force `np1` to be an array of objects:

```
np1 = np.array([1, '2' , True], dtype=object)
type(np1[0]))
#<class 'int'>
type(np1[1]))
#<class 'str'>
type(np1[2]))
#<class 'bool'>
```

Answer (score 2):

In an interactive `ipython` session, objects such as arrays are shown with their `repr` representation.  I find this to be quite informative:

```
In [41]: np1 = np.array([1,'2' , True])                                                                   
In [42]: np1                                                                                              
Out[42]: array(['1', '2', 'True'], dtype='<U21')
```

Note the quotes and `U21` dtype.  Both show that the array contains strings, that both the number and the boolean have been converted to the common string dtype.

```
In [43]: np2 = np.array([{1:1 , 2:2 }, 1 , True , '1'])                                                   
In [44]: np2                                                                                              
Out[44]: array([{1: 1, 2: 2}, 1, True, '1'], dtype=object)
In [45]: [{1:1 , 2:2 }, 1 , True , '1']                                                                   
Out[45]: [{1: 1, 2: 2}, 1, True, '1']
```

Note the `object` dtype.  And the element display is basically the same as for a list.  Such an array is practically a list.  There are some differences, but for many purposes it can be regarded as a list.  It has few advantages over a list, and some disadvantages.  It does not have have the computational speed of a numeric numpy array.

The databuffer of an object dtype array is similar to the underlying buffer of a list.  Both contain pointers or references to objects stored elsewhere in memory.  In that sense it does have a single data type - a reference.

===

If I make a list, and then make an object dtype array from that list:

```
In [48]: alist = [{1:1 , 2:2 }, 1 , True , '1']                                                           
In [49]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                            
In [50]: arr                                                                                              
Out[50]: array([{1: 1, 2: 2}, 1, True, '1'], dtype=object)
```

I can show that the dictionary in the array is the same dictionary as in the list.  They have the same `id`:

```
In [51]: id(arr[0])                                                                                       
Out[51]: 140602595005568
In [52]: id(alist[0])                                                                                     
Out[52]: 140602595005568
```

and modifications to the list, show up in the array:

```
In [53]: alist[0][3]=3                                                                                    
In [54]: arr                                                                                              
Out[54]: array([{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 1, True, '1'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to [documentation](https://numpy.org/). The first feature it supports is that it's

> a powerful N-dimensional array object

So, it deals with any element as an object

Another thing:

> Besides its obvious scientific uses, NumPy can also be used as an efficient **multi-dimensional container of *generic* data**. Arbitrary data-types can be defined. This allows NumPy to seamlessly and speedily integrate with a wide variety of databases.

So, the NumPy array tries efficiently to store its elements as the same data type if possible to optimize the performance.